# How best to send mail with server-generated attachments?

Tags: 7, emails

I've got a situation where I want to have some server-side code create a document (pdf, fwiw) and mail it to someone via drupal_mail and Mime Mail.  I've got all the appropriate modules installed, and it's working.  My problem lies in the permissions that are needed to make this happen: Mime Mail says that you must either put the files in the public webspace, or enable the "send arbitrary files" permission, which they properly note as a possible security matter.

Since the files are temporary and somewhat private, I'm creating them in temporary://, rather than leaving them visible in webspace where someone could potentially guess their names and find them in a browser.  (I'm deleting them after the message is queued, but still...)  This works, but it means that I need to enable the "send arbitrary files" permission for **anonymous users**, since it's the server that's doing the sending. This, of course, seems even worse than enabling permission for authenticated users, or some special class of user.  Blurgh.

I can kinda talk myself into thinking that it's not that bad -- the server is the only entity that can send mail in my system, and so maybe enabling this permission might be ok.  But I then think I'm kidding myself, but then I think that there aren't any alternatives.  Any suggestions out there?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer but a similar question. Did you come to any conclusion on this yourself?

Comment: Sorry; I wish I did.  I'd prefer to not hack the module, but it may come to that...